# Which tale has choice between two bowls, one of which contains a death sentence and the other a reward?

Tags: myth-identification

I have a vague recollection of a story involving an emperor asking the hero to choose between two bowls. If the hero picks the one covering a coin he will be rewarded, but if he picks the empty one he will be sentenced to death. The hero learns that the emperor is cheating and both bowls are empty, but cheats death by pointing to a bowl and saying, "I pick this one", and then lifting the other bowl to reveal it is empty. Does anybody know this tale or one with a similar theme?

Comment: This is an interesting one! I can vaguely recall such a story but cannot place it myself, will do some research until my mind stops being clogged.

Comment: Indiana Jones..